# vim enter a new line with tabspaces

Tags: vim, newline, editing

Lets say that i have this block of text

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

and i want to insert a new line above parrent::construct at the same level. Like:

```
public function __construct() {
    // this is the new line. 
    parent::__construct();
}
```

how can i do this. I try'ed to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in command mode but that will move the { down also. I managed to do it by going with the cursor to beginning of parent and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Isn't there a way to do it when the cursor is at the end of the first line ? or a shortcut to jump faster to parrent ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>o</kbd> in the normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should enable auto indention? That might solve your problems.

In your .vimrc file:

```
:set autoindent
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i am using vim plugin for netbeans ... so not all the functionality of vim is available